# underfined input foreach php to jquery

Tags: jquery, foreach, undefined

I loop with the same name in the input
I want the user to disable the javascript, the process still takes place

```
<?php 
$first = 1;
$id = array('id' => 'addcart');
foreach($data['info'] as $row):
    $first++;
    echo form_open('store/addcart/',$id); ?>
    <td width="11%" align="center"> 
        <span style="font-weight:bold;"><A href="<?=base_url().'store/products/'.$row['pcode'];?>" class="linkleft"><?=$row['pname'];?></a></span>
        <BR><SPAN class=pdesc><A href="<?=base_url().'store/products/'.$row['pcode'];?>"> Xem Chi tiết</a></SPAN>
        <BR>Giá: <span><?=$row['pprice'];?></span>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['pcode'];?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?=$row['pprice'];?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?=$row['pname'];?>"/>
        <BR><INPUT type="submit" id="submit"><div id="loading"></div>
    </TD>
    <?php
    echo form_close();
    if($first == 4) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
endforeach;
?>
```

And I sent to jquery to check, but it undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("form#addcart").submit(function() { 
        // Get the product ID and the quantity   
        var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();
        var qty = $(this).find('input[name=qty]').val();

        alert('ID:' + id + '\n\rQTY:' + qty);  

        return false;
    });  

});  
</script>
```

how to send one item is selected in the foreach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be multiple forms as you created the `forms` in a `for loop`

So apply a `class` to each `form` like
using

```
$id = array('id' => 'addcart','class'=>'addtocart');
```

and in `jQuery` use that `class name` to `submit`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(document).on('submit',"form.addtocart",function(e) {//use class name in form
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // Get the product ID and the quantity   
        var id = $(this).find('input[name=id]').val();
        var qty = $(this).find('input[name=qty]').val();
        alert('ID:' + id + '\n\rQTY:' + qty);  
        return false;
    }); 
});  
</script>
```

Comment: 'class'=>'addtocart' and $("form.addtocart"). JQuery not work, please help! undefine :(

Comment: @chiviyeu Test the above answer I have made changes.

Comment: thank you, it redirect to ...store/addcart, which means jquery not working

Comment: @chiviyeu There was an error in the above code I corrected ti now you can test once again, or you can use `$(document).on('click',"form.addtocart #submit",function(){`.

Comment: Have you added any version of `jQuery`

Comment: thank you, I think the problem lies in the foreach, when I try to closest('td'), it alert on the same id for all products?